# Android TV Preferences Standard

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-tv

When viewing the Android TV preferences and the built in apps such as YouTube, they appear to use a standard layout as shown here:

[image: Preference Screen 1]

[image: Preference Screen 2]

I cannot find any examples of implementing preferences on Android TV and can not find the above layouts referenced in any of the LeanBack etc libraries.

Is this a "standard" that I can reuse (like the normal Android PreferenceFragment) or do I have to design my own preference system?

The first image could be duplicated with the LeanBack "BrowseFragment" but the lower one cannot be implemented using anything that I have so far found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

The [new support libraries](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) have just been released. All hail [`GuidedStepFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/GuidedStepFragment.html)! It should be exactly what you were looking for.

---

No, unfortunately **that view is not provided as a standalone widget** in the Leanback library. If you want to take a look for yourself, [see here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/app/package-summary.html).

It can be implemented quite easily, but alas, you're on your own.

Comment: Thought that may be the case but thought it best to ask around before assuming.

Answer (score 1):

Since the time period when the original was answered, there is now a Leanback preferences support library that can be included and used.  See the following link:  http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v17-preference

In particular you not only want the GuidedStepFragment, but also to extend the BaseLeanbackPreferenceFragment.

Comment: Different answer.   There is now an actual Preference tag, the other other answer is refering to the GuidedStepFragment which is entirely different than the BaseLeanBackPreferenceFragment.  I'll update the answer to be more specific.

Comment: So far I have not see any popular App adopting the preference support v17 library. I'm wondering if it is proposed to be the next standard for preference or just a handy way to split all these things to a xml?